# "WHEN" clause with = condition fails for character data while using SQL LOADER

Tags: sql-loader

csv data

```
NAME,SALARY
XXX,10000
YYY,20100
```

CTL FILE

```
 OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
  load data
  infile '&1'
  APPEND
  into table temp_employee2
  WHEN ENAME = 'XXX'
  fields terminated by ","    
  (
    ENAME,
    SALARY
  )
```

While running the cp it goes to warning, with all the records

```
 Table TEMP_EMPLOYEE2, loaded when ENAME = 0X585858(character 'XXX')
  Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND

       Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
    ------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
   ENAME                               FIRST     *   ,       CHARACTER            
   SALARY                               NEXT     *   ,       CHARACTER            

  Record 0: Discarded - failed all WHEN clauses.
  Record 1: Discarded - failed all WHEN clauses.

 Table TEMP_EMPLOYEE2:
    0 Rows successfully loaded.
    0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
    1 Row not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
    0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

Space allocated for bind array:                  33024 bytes(64 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          1
Total logical records read:             1
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        2

Comment: Put an actual filename in the infile clause.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Gary_W, i tried that also, it gave same result.

Answer (score 0):

Since i have used OPTIONS(SKIP = 1), the loader skips the 1st row which satisfies the when condition, I had only 1 row that satisfies the when condition and so the data was not loaded into the table.